# Getting a ValueError: numpy cannot reshape array of size 5342252 to size (5342252, 200, 1) while training lstm

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am training an lstm text generator to recreate shakespeare text as a learning exercise. However, my code gets an error when I run it. 
`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 5342252 into shape (5342252,200,1)` I would appreciate any help as I am still learning the basics of lstm and rnn's.
My python code:

```
import numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.utils import np_utils

filename = "shakespeare.txt"
raw_text = open(filename, 'r').read()

chars = sorted(list(set(raw_text)))
char_to_int = {c:i for i, c in enumerate(chars)}

n_chars = len(raw_text)
n_vocab = len(chars)

seq_length = 200
dataX = []
dataY = []
for i in range(0, n_chars - seq_length):
    seq_in = raw_text[i: i+seq_length]
    seq_out = raw_text[i+seq_length]
    dataX.append([char_to_int[char]] for char in seq_in)
    dataY.append(char_to_int[seq_out])
n_patterns = len(dataX)

dataX = numpy.array(dataX)
X = numpy.reshape(dataX, (n_patterns, seq_length, 1))
X = X / float(n_vocab)
y = np_utils.to_categorical(dataY)

lstm = Sequential()
lstm.add(LSTM(256, input_shape=(X.shape[1], X.shape[2])))
lstm.add(Dropout(0.2))
lstm.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
lstm.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

filepath = "weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{loss:.4f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='loss', verbose=1, 
save_best_only=True, mode='min')
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

lstm.fit(X, y, epochs=20, batch_size=128, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `dataX.append(...)` adds to the end of a list in one long sequence. What you want to do is to build a 2D array of data, for which, one option is to declare your `dataX` and `dataY` as numpy arrays to start with and append more numpy arrays of shape (1,seq_length). See implementation below

```
seq_length = 200
dataX = numpy.empty((0,seq_length))
dataY = numpy.empty((0,1))
for i in range(0, n_chars - seq_length):
    seq_in = raw_text[i: i+seq_length]
    seq_out = raw_text[i+seq_length]
    new x = numpy.array([[char_to_int[char]] for char in seq_in]).reshape(1,-1)
    newy = numpy.array([char_to_int[seq_out]]).reshape(1,-1)
    dataX = numpy.append(dataX, newx, axis=0)
    dataY = numpy.append(dataY, newy, axis=0)
n_patterns = len(dataX)
```

However, this relies on expanding arrays `dataX` and `dataY` which is slow. A faster way is to allocate both of these memory in advance:

```
seq_length = 200
dataX = numpy.zeros((n_chars-seq_length,seq_length))
dataY = numpy.zeros((n_chars-seq_length,1))
for i in range(0, n_chars - seq_length):
    seq_in = raw_text[i: i+seq_length]
    seq_out = raw_text[i+seq_length]
    dataX[i] = [char_to_int[char] for char in seq_in]
    dataY[i] = [char_to_int[seq_out]]
n_patterns = len(dataX)
```

Alternatively as a non-numpy option, you could just add some square brackets to the item you are appending making

```
seq_length = 200
dataX = []
dataY = []
print(numpy.shape(dataX))
for i in range(0, n_chars - seq_length):
    seq_in = raw_text[i: i+seq_length]
    seq_out = raw_text[i+seq_length]
    dataX.append([[char_to_int[char]] for char in seq_in])
    dataY.append([char_to_int[seq_out]])
n_patterns = len(dataX)
```

though this will be slower than the previous method.

Answer (score 1):

To reshape with,

```
X = numpy.reshape(dataX, (n_patterns, seq_length, 1))
```

the dimensions should be consistent.
5342252 x 200 x 1 = 1,064,505,600 should be the number of elements in dataX if you want that shape.

It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish but my guess is that

```
n_patterns = len(dataX)
```

should be

```
n_patterns = len(dataX)/seq_length
```